# Memory being allocated and not released each time call very simple method

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, grand-central-dispatch, textdocumentproxy

I have the following method that is called when the delete button is pressed in an IOS keyboard app extension:

```
func delete()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            {
                for _ in 1..<50
                {
                    (self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
                }
                print("Deletion End")
        })
}
```

However, each time this method is called my keyboard's memory usage goes up by 1-2mb and it does not come back down. This quickly results in a crash.

I am not allocating or de-allocating any objects in this thread, so I am not sure why there is a massive memory leak.

UPDATE:

I changed `dispatch_get_main_queue()` to a static variable:

```
let mainqueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

and used `mainqueue` inplace of `dispatch_get_main_queue` but this did not do anything.

UPDATE 2:

I added a variable called `tempProxy` that is created each time delete is called:

`let tempProxy = (self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput)`

Then in `dispatch_async` I used this:

```
tempProxy.deleteBackward()
```

I did this because I heard that having references to `self` could cause memory retention.

UPDATE 3:

I changed:

```
(self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
```

to a `print()` statement.

The memory usage was now a lot less. However, I was confused as to why the memory was still not being released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had NSZombie Objects enabled which left a permanent memory increase each time I called `deleteBackward()`